# Magento 2.2.x admin config, multiple times

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, system-config

I have a question, does anyone know if it is possible to add an admin config field to each payment method without declaring it for each system config section separately?

For example, I have an admin config field. I would like to make it dynamic, meaning that whenever a new payment method appears - that admin config would appear right in the new payment method settings section.

Thank you.